# Do I need mana to play an instant that lets me block my opponents attack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

It is my opponent's turn and I decide to play [Spidery Grasp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpidery%20Grasp%5d) (1 Green mana and 2 generic mana) to attempt to untap my creature and block his creature. However all my mana is tapped, so can I still do it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on where your confusion comes in? Do you understand how casting costs in general work for spells? What reason do you have for thinking you might be allowed to cast a spell if you can't pay for it?

Comment: Also, make sure you understand the different between Lands and Mana. Mana cannot ever be tapped.

Comment: I'm new to this, but i think my question was answered, if my lands are all tapped i cant cast my instant because i cant pay for it to be casted

Comment: My confusion was whether or not you knew what the "1 Green mana and 2 generic mana" meant. If you know it is a casting cost, then what's the uncertainty. If you didn't know, then your real question is more about how to cast spells in general.

Comment: Costs would be pointless if you could forgo paying them when you can't afford them.

Comment: Exactly, thus my request for clarification... what is the actual underlying question here? If costs apply the same no matter whose turn it is? If costs on instants work the same as costs on any other spell?

Comment: @GendoIkari Sorry bout that, your confusion may have stemmed from my edit. Check the edit history to see the original wording of the question. It seems to boil down to the OP not understanding how spell casting works, and that you need to tap lands to add mana not simply have 1 forest and 2 other lands(which seems to be fairly common confusion among new players).

Comment: @Malco No, I had looked at the edits; I don't think your edit changed the meaning of anything. If he thought that just having the lands is enough, then why would the lands be tapped?

Comment: To the close votes... while I highly suspect that there is an underlying question or rules misconception at play; the question as asked is clear and answerable, so I don't think it should be closed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you need mana in order to cast spells that require mana. You can't just cast [Spidery Grasp](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpidery%20Grasp%5d) for nothing; it costs {2}{G}. If you have no mana available, and all your mana sources aren't available to be used (e.g. all your lands are tapped out already), you will have no mana to cast it with.

Lands and cards like [Llanowar Elves](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLlanowar%20Elves%5d) can be tapped to give you mana, but won't give you mana merely by existing.

I suggest you give the game's [Quick Start Booklet](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf) (PDF link) a read. It might clarify things for you.